# possibility of having docker-swarm and kubernetes together

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

Can I run both docker swarm and kubernetes on same nodes , can overlay network and kubernetes internal cluster network work together ?

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, but it's not as good an idea as it sounds at first. Unfortunately it confuses Kubernetes about the amount of resources available on the nodes.